# Regular expression to search for specific twitter username

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I have a project where I'm trying to analyze a database of tweets. I need to write a python regex expression that pulls tweets mentioning specific twitter users. Here is an example tweet I'd like to capture.

"That @A_Person is a real jerk."

The regex that I've been trying is

```
([^.?!]*)(\b([@]A_Person)\b)([^.?!]*)
```

But it's not working and I've tried lots of variations. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: How about `if '@A_Person' in tweet: ` ?

Comment: Why not simply `[@]A_Person\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` matches a word boundary, but `@` is not a word character, so if it occurs after a space, the match will fail. Try removing the word boundary there, and removing the extra groups, and add a character set at the end for `[.?!]` to include the final punctuation, and you get:

```
[^.?!]*@A_Person\b.*?[^.?!]*[.?!]
```

You also might consider including a check for the start of the string or the end of the last sentence, otherwise the engine will go through a *lot* of steps while going through areas without any matches. Perhaps use

```
(?:^|(?<=[.?!])\s*)
```

which will match the start of the string, or will lookbehind for `[.?!]` possibly followed by spaces. Put those together and you get

```
(?:^|(?<=[.?!])\s*)([^.?!]*@A_Person\b.*?[^.?!]*[.?!])
```

where the string you want is in the first group (no leading spaces).

https://regex101.com/r/447KsF/3

Comment: `.*?[.?!]` is much worse in terms of performance than `[^.?!]*[.?!]`. Best practice is to avoid lazy quantifiers if greedy ones will do. Unless one wants to stay within a line.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I need to remember that a bit less code repetition might not be worth it in exchange for performance with regular expressions